# How best to collect messages from many sources?

Tags: php, logging, messaging

I am working through the planning for a new project where the goal is to collect messages from many sources in one place. Basically different websites on different servers on the same network need to report some information on actions being taken to a central logger. I want this to be a service offered to the clients, in that each site just fires off a message to central. It does not need to respond that the message was actually recieved, and it is ok if it drops messages under load. I would prefer that it could response that the message was recieved and logged, if requested by the client.

I am working with PHP on the site side, and would prefer to work with it on the logging side as well. Can anyone give me insight into any protocol or architecture that might work for this?

Edit
Alternatively, are there any messaging libraries anyone would suggest? I am looking for any good answers on protocol or design, from what db might be easiest to scale, to what network protocol it could speak. Would UDP be good for something like this? Speed of message sending is the most important factor in this design.

I'm working with one server currently for the logging in the plan.

Comment: Well, you need to look at some more "system" languages and UDP then

Comment: Does it have to be a single log file?  (Is the logger actually even a file?)  Can it be multiple logs that are combined later?  Do you feel that HTTP is a bad protocol to use for some reason?

Comment: @Marvo: http as an application layer protocol over tcp/ip is much worse in comparison to UDP in high loaded environments.

Comment: In general, yes, but depends on the requirements as well.  If multiple log files can be assembled on the back end after the fact, then a farm of simple PHP pages that simply receive a message and write it to a log file, multiplexed in some fashion, would scale nicely.  "It's okay if it drops messages under load" doesn't necessarily mean "drop message any time if that's easier."

Definitely wrap an API around the logging class you drop into the client so that if you need to change the underlying protocol, you simply replace the API or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking towards a message queueing system as the middle, with the logger behind it collecting the messages and processing them.

Some of the choices I have found are RabbitMQ, Kestrel, and Beanstalkd.

Answer (score 1):

I'd *strongly* recommend using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for this. Getting a server up and running is trivial (see [this link](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/dgram.html#dgram.bind) for a sample of a UDP-based server). There are database modules that you can install for node ([npm](http://npmjs.org/) is great for installing 3rd party modules) as they're not native to node.js.

With its non-blocking nature, I'm pretty sure that you'd put anything written in PHP to shame in terms of performance.